# OptionGroup horizontal?

Tags: java, frameworks, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying change an OptionGroup to display Horizontal. In vaadin7 book there an example to change with CSS, but doesn't work.

I'm trying this.

```
//styles.scss
/** optiongroup */
/* Lay the options horizontally */
.v-select-optiongroup-horizontal .v-select-option {
    display: inline-block;
}
/* Avoid wrapping if the layout is too tight */
.v-select-optiongroup-horizontal {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
/* Some extra spacing is needed */
.v-select-optiongroup-horizontal .v-select-option.v-radiobutton {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```
//Here the OptionGroup
OptionGroup optionGroup = new OptionGroup();
optionGroup.addItem("Usuário");
optionGroup.addItem("Representante");
```

Any idea?

Comment: now works. I add addStyleName("horizontal") and change :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As written in the book you need to set a custom horizontal style name:

```
optionGroup.addStyleName("horizontal");
```

Comment: In the new Valo theme, you can use `ValoTheme.OPTIONGROUP_HORIZONTAL` as the style name for horizontal orientation in an `OptionGroup `.

Comment: but If I want to show in grid wise because I have more than 20 component add in optionGroup ...How can I do it ?